# Using .values() with list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, json, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I'm comparing json files between two different API endpoints to see which json records need an update, which need a create and what needs a delete. So, by comparing the two json files, I want to end up with three json files, one for each operation.

The json at both endpoints is structured like this (but they use different keys for same sets of values; different problem):

```
{
    "records": [{
        "id": "id-value-here",
        "c": {
            "d": "eee"
        },
        "f": {
            "l": "last",
            "f": "first"
        },
        "g": ["100", "89", "9831", "09112", "800"]
    }, {

        …


    }]
}
```

So the json is represented as a list of dictionaries (with further nested lists and dictionaries).

If a given json endpoint (j1) id value ("id":) exists in the other endpoint json (j2), then that record should be added to j_update.

So far I have something like this, but I can see that .values() doesn't work because it's trying to operate on the list instead of on all the listed dictionaries(?):

```
j_update = {r for r in j1['records'] if r['id'] in 
j2.values()}
```

This doesn't return an error, but it creates an empty set using test json files.

Seems like this should be simple, but tripping over the nesting I think of dictionaries in a list representing the json. Do I need to flatten j2, or is there a simpler dictionary method python has to achieve this?

====edit j1 and j2==== 
have same structure, use different keys; toy data

### j1

```
{
    "records": [{
        "field_5": 2329309841,
        "field_12": {
            "email": "cmix@etest.com"
        },
        "field_20": {
            "last": "Mixalona",
            "first": "Clara"
        },
        "field_28": ["9002329309999", "9002329309112"],
        "field_44": ["1002329309832"]
    }, {
        "field_5": 2329309831,
        "field_12": {
            "email": "mherbitz345@test.com"
        },
        "field_20": {
            "last": "Herbitz",
            "first": "Michael"
        },
        "field_28": ["9002329309831", "9002329309112", "8002329309999"],
        "field_44": ["1002329309832"]
    }, {
        "field_5": 2329309855,
        "field_12": {
            "email": "nkatamaran@test.com"
        },
        "field_20": {
            "first": "Noriss",
            "last": "Katamaran"
        },
        "field_28": ["9002329309111", "8002329309112"],
        "field_44": ["1002329309877"]
    }]
}
```

### j2

```
{
    "records": [{
        "id": 2329309831,
        "email": {
            "email": "mherbitz345@test.com"
        },
        "name_primary": {
            "last": "Herbitz",
            "first": "Michael"
        },
        "assign": ["8003329309831", "8007329309789"],
        "hr_id": ["1002329309877"]
    }, {
        "id": 2329309884,
        "email": {
            "email": "yinleeshu@test.com"
        },
        "name_primary": {
            "last": "Lee Shu",
            "first": "Yin"
        },
        "assign": ["8002329309111", "9003329309831", "9002329309111", "8002329309999", "8002329309112"],
        "hr_id": ["1002329309832"]
    }, {
        "id": 23293098338,
        "email": {
            "email": "amlouis@test.com"
        },
        "name_primary": {
            "last": "Maxwell Louis",
            "first": "Albert"
        },
        "assign": ["8002329309111", "8007329309789", "9003329309831", "8002329309999", "8002329309112"],
        "hr_id": ["1002329309877"]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Is `j2` the outermost dict in the shown strucutre?

Comment: Please supply a [MCVE] structure of both `j1` and `j2` for comparison.

Comment: is `j_update` supposed to be a `dict` or `list`? Or is it meant as a `set` as your code implies?

Comment: @schwobaseggl j2 is a separate json file from a different api endpoint

Comment: @Idlehands Thanks -- I added an edit in question with some toy data sets that show the structure.

Comment: @Idlehands j_update just needs to be json at the end to send to a PUT request.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the json it will output a dict. You are looking for a particular key in the list of the values.

```
if 'records' in j2:
  r = j2['records'][0].get('id', []) # defaults if id does not exist
```

It it prettier to do a recursive search but i dunno how you data is organized to quickly come up with a solution.

To give an idea for recursive search consider this example

```
def resursiveSearch(dictionary, target):
    if target in dictionary:
        return dictionary[target]
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            target = resursiveSearch(value, target)
            if target:
                return target


a = {'test' : 'b', 'test1' : dict(x = dict(z = 3), y = 2)}

print(resursiveSearch(a, 'z'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You tried:

```
j_update = {r for r in j1['records'] if r['id'] in j2.values()}
```

Aside from the `r['id'/'field_5]` problem, you have:

```
>>> list(j2.values())
[[{'id': 2329309831, ...}, ...]]
```

The `id` are buried inside a list and a dict, thus the test `r['id'] in j2.values()` always return False.

The basic solution is fairly simple.
First, create a set of `j2` `id`s:

```
>>> present_in_j2 = set(record["id"] for record in j2["records"])
```

Then, rebuild the json structure of `j1` but without the `j1` `field_5` that are not present in `j2`:

```
>>> {"records":[record for record in j1["records"] if record["field_5"] in present_in_j2]}
{'records': [{'field_5': 2329309831, 'field_12': {'email': 'mherbitz345@test.com'}, 'field_20': {'last': 'Herbitz', 'first': 'Michael'}, 'field_28': ['9002329309831', '9002329309112', '8002329309999'], 'field_44': ['1002329309832']}]}
```

It works, but it's not totally satisfying because of the weird keys of `j1`. Let's try to convert `j1` to a more friendly format:

```
def map_keys(json_value, conversion_table):
    """Map the keys of a json value
    This is a recursive DFS"""

    def map_keys_aux(json_value):
        """Capture the conversion table"""
        if isinstance(json_value, list):
            return [map_keys_aux(v) for v in json_value]
        elif isinstance(json_value, dict):
            return {conversion_table.get(k, k):map_keys_aux(v) for k,v in json_value.items()}
        else:
            return json_value

    return map_keys_aux(json_value)
```

The function focuses on dictionary keys: `conversion_table.get(k, k)` is `conversion_table[k]` if the key is present in the conversion table, or the key itself otherwise.

```
>>> j1toj2 = {"field_5":"id", "field_12":"email", "field_20":"name_primary", "field_28":"assign", "field_44":"hr_id"}
>>> mapped_j1 = map_keys(j1, j1toj2)
```

Now, the code is cleaner and the output may be more useful for a `PUT`:

```
>>> d1 = {record["id"]:record for record in mapped_j1["records"]}
>>> present_in_j2 = set(record["id"] for record in j2["records"])
>>> {"records":[record for record in mapped_j1["records"] if record["id"] in present_in_j2]}
{'records': [{'id': 2329309831, 'email': {'email': 'mherbitz345@test.com'}, 'name_primary': {'last': 'Herbitz', 'first': 'Michael'}, 'assign': ['9002329309831', '9002329309112', '8002329309999'], 'hr_id': ['1002329309832']}]}
```